# Failed to run analysis SonarQube 5.2 from Jenkins with specific artifact name

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.2

I recently upgraded to 5.2
Some of my jenkins process can not run SonarQube analysis (may be it failed with previous versions ?)

After running with debug mode, the stack trace is the following :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project myclient-extractor:
    Fail to execute request [code=500,url=http:// www.dev.jouvinio.net/sonar/batch/project.protobuf?key=net.jouvinio.myclient%3Amyclient-extractor]:
    Fail to download [http:// www.dev.jouvinio.net/sonar/batch/project.protobuf?key=net.jouvinio.myclient%3Amyclient-extractor].
    Response code: 500 -  [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.7.1:sonar (default-cli) on project myclient-extractor:
  Fail to execute request [code=500, url=http:// www.dev.jouvinio.net/sonar/batch/project.protobuf?key=net.jouvinio.myclient%3Amyclient-extractor]
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException:
  Fail to execute request [code=500,url=http:// www.dev.jouvinio.net/sonar/batch/project.protobuf?key=net.jouvinio.myclient%3Amyclient-extractor]
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstrapper.execute(RunnerBootstrapper.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
  Fail to execute request [code=500,url=http:// www.dev.jouvinio.net/sonar/batch/project.protobuf?key=net.jouvinio.myclient%3Amyclient-extractor]
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.handleHttpException(ServerClient.java:138)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.load(ServerClient.java:121)
    at org.sonar.batch.cache.WSLoader$3.load(WSLoader.java:86)
    at org.sonar.batch.cache.WSLoader$3.load(WSLoader.java:83)
    at org.sonar.batch.cache.WSLoader.loadFromServer(WSLoader.java:233)
    at org.sonar.batch.cache.WSLoader.loadFromServerFirst(WSLoader.java:194)
    at org.sonar.batch.cache.WSLoader.load(WSLoader.java:154)
    at org.sonar.batch.cache.WSLoader.loadStream(WSLoader.java:130)
    at org.sonar.batch.repository.DefaultProjectRepositoriesLoader.load(DefaultProjectRepositoriesLoader.java:57)
    at org.sonar.batch.repository.ProjectRepositoriesProvider.provide(ProjectRepositoriesProvider.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.invokeMethod(MethodInjector.java:129)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.access$000(MethodInjector.java:39)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector$2.run(MethodInjector.java:113)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.MethodInjector.decorateComponentInstance(MethodInjector.java:120)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.CompositeInjector.decorateComponentInstance(CompositeInjector.java:58)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.Reinjector.reinject(Reinjector.java:142)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ProviderAdapter.getComponentInstance(ProviderAdapter.java:96)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:632)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.BasicComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(BasicComponentParameter.java:118)
    at org.picocontainer.parameters.ComponentParameter$1.resolveInstance(ComponentParameter.java:136)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.SingleMemberInjector.getParameter(SingleMemberInjector.java:78)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$CtorAndAdapters.getParameterArguments(ConstructorInjector.java:309)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:335)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.getComponentInstance(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:56)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.getComponentByType(ComponentContainer.java:230)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:120)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:98)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:85)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeAnalysis(GlobalContainer.java:153)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:110)
    at org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:275)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:166)
    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:153)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstrapper.execute(RunnerBootstrapper.java:99)
    ... 23 more Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$HttpException:
  Fail to download [http:// www.dev.jouvinio.net/sonar/batch/project.protobuf?key=net.jouvinio.myclient%3Amyclient-extractor].
  Response code: 500
    at org.sonar.core.util.DefaultHttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(DefaultHttpDownloader.java:343)
    at org.sonar.core.util.DefaultHttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier.getInput(DefaultHttpDownloader.java:288)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ServerClient.load(ServerClient.java:117)
    ... 76 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http:// cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
  Build step 'Invoquer les cibles Maven de haut niveau' marked build as
  failure Started calculate disk usage of build Finished Calculation of
  disk usage of build in 0 seconds Started calculate disk usage of
  workspace Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in 0 seconds
Finished: FAILURE
```

The SonarQube trace is the following

```
2015.11.16 00:21:29 INFO web[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerRunnableImpl] Execute task | project=com.socgen.scad:batches | id=AVENdAv0hAxh5yDyBUwV
2015.11.16 00:22:08 WARN es[o.e.monitor.jvm]  [sonar-1447592960153] [gc][young][36740][10] duration [1.9s], collections [1]/[2s],
  total [1.9s]/[4.9s], memory [168.8mb]->[36.4mb]/[1007.3mb], all_pools {[young] [132.1mb]->[555kb]/[133.1mb]}
  {[survivor] [6mb]->[4.3mb]/[16.6mb]}{[old] [30.7mb]->[31.5mb]/[857.6mb]}
2015.11.16 00:22:12 INFO web[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerRunnableImpl] Executed task | project=com.socgen.scad:batches | id=AVENdAv0hAxh5yDyBUwV | time=42346ms
2015.11.16 00:25:33 INFO web[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerRunnableImpl] Execute task | project=com.socgen.scad:batches | id=AVENd8hmhAxh5yDyBU9w
2015.11.16 00:25:43 INFO web[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerRunnableImpl] Executed task | project=com.socgen.scad:batches | id=AVENd8hmhAxh5yDyBU9w | time=9854ms
2015.11.16 00:46:35 INFO es[o.e.monitor.jvm] [sonar-1447592960153] [gc][young][38206][11] duration [921ms], collections [1]/[1.1s],
  total [921ms]/[5.8s], memory [168.7mb]->[38.4mb]/[1007.3mb], all_pools {[young] [132.8mb]->[421.7kb]/[133.1mb]}
  {[survivor][4.3mb]->[6.5mb]/[16.6mb]}{[old] [31.5mb]->[31.5mb]/[857.6mb]}
2015.11.16 00:47:40 INFO web[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerRunnableImpl] Execute task | project=com.socgen.scad:batches | id=AVENjAIghAxh5yDyBU90
2015.11.16 00:47:57 INFO web[o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerRunnableImpl] Executed task | project=com.socgen.scad:batches | id=AVENjAIghAxh5yDyBU90 | time=17409ms
2015.11.16 01:14:57 ERROR web[o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request
  http://www.dev.jouvinio.net/sonar/batch/project.protobuf?key=net.jouvinio.myclient%3Amyclient-extractor
  java.lang.NullPointerException: null at com.google.protobuf.Utf8.encodedLength(Utf8.java:378)
  ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na] at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream.computeStringSizeNoTag(CodedOutputStream.java:911)
  ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na] at com.google.protobuf.FieldSet.computeElementSizeNoTag(FieldSet.java:834)
  ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na] at com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite.getFieldSize(MapEntryLite.java:143)
  ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na] at com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite.getSerializedSize(MapEntryLite.java:135)
  ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na] at com.google.protobuf.MapEntry.getSerializedSize(MapEntry.java:120)
  ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na] at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream.computeMessageSizeNoTag(CodedOutputStream.java:947)
  ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na] at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream.computeMessageSize(CodedOutputStream.java:707)
  ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na] at org.sonarqube.ws.WsBatch$WsProjectResponse$FileDataByPath.getSerializedSize(WsBatch.java:783)
```

Other projets can be analyzed.
The only thing I can see, is the fact that the artifact name contains the caracter minus, and the project key is something like this : net.jouvinio.myclient:myclient-extractor

It also appends on multi module project, and when a sub module contains this caracter.

EDIT on 19th november :
Problem seems to not be link to project name with -
I deleted one project in SonarQube and reload analysis. It works fine. Invest in progress.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce. I tried with minus and more exotic characters at the module/file level. I tested with multi-module and empty files, without success. I've created a [ticket](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7040) to give more context when failing

Comment: It probably fails because some component paths are null. A related jira ticket has been created: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7084

Answer (score 3):

You are probably experiencing this bug: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7008

For the time being I would recommend try changing the project key.

Comment: Thanks.
I saw that issue, but it deals with quality profile name.

I try to call the URL with manual encoding, but no effect. I will give a try to change the project key value. But the project is a Maven one, and everything was fine for mee before.
Imagine, you have to say all Apache Commons project to change the configuration (if the - in project key is the cause)

Comment: I may said a mistake by the way.
I have a project with sub module that contains - in the artifactId.

I will investigate a little bit more

Comment: You are right, the ticket is related to quality profile and not to project key. It is probably not related to URL encoding. Please update the question if you manage to get more information on how to reproduce.