# Update SonarQube 5.2 UTF-8 issue

Tags: mysql, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube5.2

I updated my Sonar 3.4.2 working with MySQL database to SonarQube 5.2 (following the upgrade procedures). But now my Jenkins Jobs failed all the time.

My shorted stacktrace:

```
2015.11.26 09:40:16 ERROR web[o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://se02/sonarqube/batch/project.protobuf?key=de.adnova%3Amodule.benutzerunterstuetzung
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
         at com.google.protobuf.Utf8.encodedLength(Utf8.java:378) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na]
         at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream.computeStringSizeNoTag(CodedOutputStream.java:911) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na]
         at com.google.protobuf.FieldSet.computeElementSizeNoTag(FieldSet.java:834) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na]
         at com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite.getFieldSize(MapEntryLite.java:143) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na]
         at com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite.getSerializedSize(MapEntryLite.java:135) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na]
         at com.google.protobuf.MapEntry.getSerializedSize(MapEntry.java:120) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na]
         at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream.computeMessageSizeNoTag(CodedOutputStream.java:947) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na]
         at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream.computeMessageSize(CodedOutputStream.java:707) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na]
         at org.sonarqube.ws.WsBatch$WsProjectResponse$FileDataByPath.getSerializedSize(WsBatch.java:783) ~[sonar-ws-5.2.jar:na]
         at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream.computeMessageSizeNoTag(CodedOutputStream.java:947) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na]
         at com.google.protobuf.FieldSet.computeElementSizeNoTag(FieldSet.java:846) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na]
         at com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite.getFieldSize(MapEntryLite.java:143) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na]
         at com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite.getSerializedSize(MapEntryLite.java:136) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na]
         at com.google.protobuf.MapEntry.getSerializedSize(MapEntry.java:120) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na]
         at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream.computeMessageSizeNoTag(CodedOutputStream.java:947) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na]
         at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream.computeMessageSize(CodedOutputStream.java:707) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na]
         at org.sonarqube.ws.WsBatch$WsProjectResponse.getSerializedSize(WsBatch.java:1856) ~[sonar-ws-5.2.jar:na]
         at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite.writeTo(AbstractMessageLite.java:77) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-1.jar:na]
         at org.sonar.server.ws.WsUtils.writeProtobuf(WsUtils.java:48) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
         at org.sonar.server.batch.ProjectAction.handle(ProjectAction.java:83) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
         at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:85) ~[sonar-server-5.2.jar:na]
         at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor166.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
         at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:425) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:292) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:44) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:70) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.Api::JavaWsController$$index_F0093F46F7B98A69318D6BFF77A0745BB14C850A115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/java_ws_controller.rb:34) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.Api::JavaWsController$$index_F0093F46F7B98A69318D6BFF77A0745BB14C850A115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/java_ws_controller.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:527) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2590) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2223) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$perform_action_DA0FC0A901DD1257EC969DB0C482DD8514B8F04B115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1333) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$perform_action_DA0FC0A901DD1257EC969DB0C482DD8514B8F04B115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:185) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$call_filters_A7E1D3FFBF56E3CB7C0EBA850688505249A05AE9115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$call_filters_A7E1D3FFBF56E3CB7C0EBA850688505249A05AE9115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:261) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:236) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$perform_action_with_filters_4C7C67B4A5564FF5DC76344AF2372660F608839C115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$perform_action_with_filters_4C7C67B4A5564FF5DC76344AF2372660F608839C115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:185) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Benchmarking$$perform_action_with_benchmark_303676EADF39D1B66CBA6FF2131B0D6C74E04345115612850.block_0$RUBY$__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit$ActionController::Benchmarking$$perform_action_with_benchmark_303676EADF39D1B66CBA6FF2131B0D6C74E04345115612850$block_0$RUBY$__file__.call(rubyjit$ActionController::Benchmarking$$perform_action_with_benchmark_303676EADF39D1B66CBA6FF2131B0D6C74E04345115612850$block_0$RUBY$__file__) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:112) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:95) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yieldSpecific(CompiledBlock.java:75) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.Module$$ms_A9C6E2920290A1221EDA9CE357DE380BBA9B1BD9115612850.block_0$RUBY$__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit$Module$$ms_A9C6E2920290A1221EDA9CE357DE380BBA9B1BD9115612850$block_0$RUBY$__file__.call(rubyjit$Module$$ms_A9C6E2920290A1221EDA9CE357DE380BBA9B1BD9115612850$block_0$RUBY$__file__) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:112) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yield(CompiledBlock.java:95) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock.yieldSpecific(CompiledBlock.java:75) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:111) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.Benchmark$$realtime_D80759D5ED3DED92A37F972B3598DFDF9CC64E2A115612850.__file__(jar:file:/D:/SEU/Sonarqube/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.Benchmark$$realtime_D80759D5ED3DED92A37F972B3598DFDF9CC64E2A115612850.__file__(jar:file:/D:/SEU/Sonarqube/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:193) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.WrapperMethod.call(WrapperMethod.java:74) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.Module$$ms_A9C6E2920290A1221EDA9CE357DE380BBA9B1BD9115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.Module$$ms_A9C6E2920290A1221EDA9CE357DE380BBA9B1BD9115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Benchmarking$$perform_action_with_benchmark_303676EADF39D1B66CBA6FF2131B0D6C74E04345115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Benchmarking$$perform_action_with_benchmark_303676EADF39D1B66CBA6FF2131B0D6C74E04345115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:185) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Rescue$$perform_action_with_rescue_C881D7FD614DB6154FDE67AADAA1B18CFBA9E44D115612850.chained_0_rescue_1$RUBY$SYNTHETIC__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Rescue$$perform_action_with_rescue_C881D7FD614DB6154FDE67AADAA1B18CFBA9E44D115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Rescue$$perform_action_with_rescue_C881D7FD614DB6154FDE67AADAA1B18CFBA9E44D115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:185) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:56) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Flash::InstanceMethods$$perform_action_with_flash_00190F39E4A509D41D1870DF577ADEFF4F2D86E0115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Flash::InstanceMethods$$perform_action_with_flash_00190F39E4A509D41D1870DF577ADEFF4F2D86E0115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:193) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:81) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:527) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.send(RubyBasicObject.java:2590) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(RubyKernel.java:2223) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$send.gen) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodOneOrNBlock.call(JavaMethod.java:350) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callVarargs(CachingCallSite.java:103) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$process_0CD993B4C06E435A5AD30338E2A0816E50206655115612850.chained_0_ensure_1$RUBY$__ensure__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$process_0CD993B4C06E435A5AD30338E2A0816E50206655115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Base$$process_0CD993B4C06E435A5AD30338E2A0816E50206655115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.ast.executable.AbstractScript.__file__(AbstractScript.java:50) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:261) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:233) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.AliasMethod.call(AliasMethod.java:71) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:236) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callVarargs(CachingCallSite.java:105) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$process_with_filters_77F73D0F3CFC9652FC1D8F99FD6ECB9ACFAEB2BE115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::Filters::InstanceMethods$$process_with_filters_77F73D0F3CFC9652FC1D8F99FD6ECB9ACFAEB2BE115612850.__file__(D:/SEU/Sonarqube/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.ast.executable.AbstractScript.__file__(AbstractScript.java:46) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:221) at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
         at rubyjit.ActionController::StringCoercion$$call_D51288B7BF2BE6EC36483A8B41C5A7EAEorg.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.18.jar:8.0.18]
         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_66]
```

It seems to be a problem with the text format. Has anyone an idea to fix this?

I found this : [SONAR-7008](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7008) , but I can not wait for the 5.3 release.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727042/failed-to-run-analysis-sonarqube-5-2-from-jenkins-with-specific-artifact-name ?